# Junit Test Case

Tags: junit

I wanted to write junit for below method "createEmailTripEvent()", So i was trying to mock EmailTrip interface by using EasyMock but couldn't able to proceed.

Is it possible to use EasyMock for mocking interface or we need to go for Mockito only ?
If Mockito is the only option, then anybody can explain me how we can use ?

Please refer below class & Interface

```java
private EmailTrip emailTrip;

public ModelAndView createEmailTripEvent (HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    emailTrip.createEmailTripEvent(Code, emailRequest);
    //Need to write junit for above method
}

public interface EmailTrip {
    void createEmailTripEvent(String code, TripEmailRequest request)
            throws Exception;
}

public class EmailTripImpl implements EmailTrip { }
```

Comment: You could use EasyMock or Mockito. Both libraries will work. Please explain why you are not able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the following dependency to your maven pom (if not using maven, urgently consider doing so...). Otherwise include the EasyMock dependency to your class path.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
  <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After that you should be able to create your test class.

```java
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
import org.easymock.*;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTinyTest extends EasyMockSupport {
  @Rule
  public EasyMockRule rule = new EasyMockRule(this);

  @Mock
  private EmailTrip emailTrip;

  @TestSubject
  private final ServletClass servlet = new ServletClass(emailTrip);

  @Test
  public void testCreateEmailTripEvent() {
    // you should know how to create an email request instance!
    EmailTripRequest emailRequest = createRequest();
    // tell EasyMock what behavior is expected...
    emailTrip.createEmailTripEvent("code", emailRequest);

    // start testing...
    replayAll();
    // excute method to test...
    ModelAndView result = servlet.createEmailTripEvent(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    // verify if expected behavior occured.
    verifyAll();

    // check other assertions concerning the method result...
  }
}
```